# ASP.NET MVC Web API Primitive Post not binding Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/client/log")]
    public void SetClientLog([FromBody]string error)
    {
        ClientLogger.LogError(error);
    }
```

And in angular i'm trying to post the following where log is just a string

```
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "api/client/log",
                data: log,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            });
```

Comment: here data should be a object...like: `data:{log : log}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you prefix your value with "=" and set the correct Content-Type:

```
 $http.post('api/Companies/Search', "="+$scope.query, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
            })
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.result = data;  
                })
                 .error(function (data, status) {
                       $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                       $scope.status = status;
                   });
```